# Covariance structure for several mixed models with similar dependent variables

Tags: regression, mixed-model, covariance-matrix, fitting

I want to fit several mixed models which only differ by their dependent variable. However these dependent variables are not totally different but fatty acids with similar characteristics. I know there are several possible covariance structures which seem reasonable. However, the  covariance structure with the highest fit (according to BIC, AIC, AICc) is not identical across these fatty acids even though the results are quite close. So my question is, what to do

1. select the best covariance structure for each fatty acid independently
2. select the (on average?) best covariance structure across the different fatty acids

I would also be delighted if someone could provide some further references to read. All articles that I found only discussed selecting the covariance structure for a single model.

Comment: It may not be possible with your software but wouldn't it be interesting to fit all three DVs simultaneously, like a mixed model MANOVA? In this way you could test each covariance structure.

Comment: @MikeHunter It is indeed an interesting thought, however, due to some other constraints, this is not feasible I am afraid. As a side note, there are way more than three DVs (or is it a typo and you wanted to write "the"?).